# Defined a variable still getting an undefined reference error

Tags: c, linker-errors, extern

x,y,z are 3 variables defined and declared in a function of radius_of_3_circles.c file. Once that function executes i.e. radius_x_y_z(); //line number 81 in code. The values of x,y,z get updated I want to use that in hit.c .  I define x,y,z as extern in hit.c but still am getting an undefined reference error.

First I had a .h file but was getting a lot of linker errors and confusion.Therfore I brought all of the declarations in .c file only. Rest of the errors have gone but this keeps on coming.
[image]

[image]

**radius_of_3_circles.c**

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include  <stdint.h>
void radius_x_y_z(void);

void radius_x_y_z(void)
{
int x;//extern
int y;//extern
int z;//extern
x=5;
y=3;
z=84;

}
```

**hit.c**

```
#include  <stdint.h>
#include "math.h"

void hit(void);

void hit(void)
{
     int a,s,X,Y,Z;
     int L=165;
     extern int x;//extern
     extern int y;//extern
     extern int z;//extern
     extern void radius_x_y_z(void);

     radius_x_y_z();
     s=x+y;

    if(s < L)
    {
        a = (L-s)/2 ; //inflate by a
        X = x + a;
        Y = y + a; //getting error here.
        Z = z + a;
    }

}
```

Not removing the pictures.Keeping them for reference and if someone  wants to see the error msg.

Comment: You can't `define as extern`, if you add `extern` then that's a declaration, you need to remove `extern` when making your definition. Please also add a [mre] to future questions and don't tag c++ in c questions and vice versa

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry missed to add the picture. I have defined the variables in another .c file and am using it in hit.c file. Therefore mentioned extern before declaring the variabes.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, just post the text in a properly formatted code block

Comment: @AlanBirtles Have attached the Minimal reproducible code. Kept the pictures just in case

Comment: Your variables inside `radius_x_y_z` are not the same variables as you declared in the global scope

Comment: @AlanBirtles How come? It is x,y,z that are global and i am storing their value in X,Y,Z which is local to hit()

Comment: @AlanBirtles If it is some silly error then please just say it, I am trying to solve this from past 2 days and still can't find it. Have I used the extern keyword correctly ?

Comment: they're local variables to the function, they have the same name as your global variables but are otherwise unrelated. You must declare and define variables in exactly the same scope otherwise they are two separate sets of variables

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is why I have added the term extern. In hit.c I am declaring them as extern and also defining them, so isn't it in the same scope?

Comment: no, they're function local variables, global variables can only be defined in global scope

Comment: ohh got it thnnks @AlanBirtles